# ''TypeError at /user expected string or bytes-like object'' on submitting the for in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When I submitting the form in django it is giving error ''TypeError at /user expected string or bytes-like object''.

This is my staff models

```
class staff(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    salary = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateField()
```

This is my user views.

```
def user(request):
    if request.method == "POST" :
        name = request.POST['name']
        role = request.POST['role']
        salary = request.POST['salary']
        address = request.POST['address']
        number = request.POST['number']
        date = DateTimeField()

        ins = staff(name=name, role=role, salary=salary, address=address, date=date, number=number)
        ins.save()
    staffs = staff.objects.all()
    return render(request, "salary/user.html", {'staff': staffs})
```

and this is form of template user.html

```
<form class="forms-sample" action="/user" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="exampleInputUsername2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Name:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername2" placeholder="Username">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="exampleInputUsername2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Role:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="role" id="role" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername2" placeholder="Role">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="exampleInputUsername2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Salary:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="salary" id="salary" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername2" placeholder="Salary">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="exampleInputUsername2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Address:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername2" placeholder="Address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="exampleInputUsername2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Mobile no.:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername2" placeholder="Mobile no.">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Submit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-dark">Cancel</button>
                        </form>
```

I am new in django and i not know what the problem is.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: `date = DateTimeField()` makes no sense, you should parse that from the `request.POST` data, or work with a Django form to convert this to a valid `date` object.

Comment: how can i do it

Comment: do you want to fill in the *current* date?

Comment: yes i want to fill current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to pass a reference to the `AutoField` model field in your model, you should *construct* a field, so:

```
class staff(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField()
    # ⋮
```

as for the `date` field, you can work with [**`auto_now_add=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) to automatically fill in the current day:

```
class staff(models.Model):
    # ⋮
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

then this can be omitted while constructing a `staff` object:

```
def user(request):
    if request.method == "POST" :
        name = request.POST['name']
        role = request.POST['role']
        salary = request.POST['salary']
        address = request.POST['address']
        number = request.POST['number']

        #           no date=… ↓
        ins = staff.objects.create(name=name, role=role, salary=salary, address=address, number=number)
        ins.save()
    staffs = staff.objects.all()
    return render(request, "salary/user.html", {'staff': staffs})
```

It might however be better to work with [*Django forms*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) to validate, clean and fill in data from a POST request.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`staff`</s> to `Staff`.